# npm start on cmd after creating react app always gives error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm

I have created a Simple React App and succeed because it already showed the happy hacking message on cmd, however when i type and ran "npm start" on cmd it gives a lot of errors. I've tried to uninstall then install the node and npm several times but it still doesn't work. here's the error message

```
Creating a new React app in C:\myapp2.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...


> core-js@2.6.10 postinstall C:\myapp2\node_modules\babel-runtime\node_modules\core-js
> node postinstall || echo "ignore"


> core-js@3.2.1 postinstall C:\myapp2\node_modules\core-js
> node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"

+ react-dom@16.11.0
+ react@16.11.0
+ react-scripts@3.2.0
added 1475 packages from 693 contributors and audited 904933 packages in 828.526s
found 0 vulnerabilities


Success! Created myapp2 at C:\myapp2
Starting the development server...

events.js:187
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:264:19)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21)
Emitted 'error' event on ChildProcess instance at:
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)
    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:80:21) {
  errno: 'ENOENT',
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'spawn cmd',
  path: 'cmd',
  spawnargs: [ '/c', 'start', '""', '/b', 'http://localhost:3000/' ]
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! myapp2@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the myapp2@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\ASUS\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-11-13T21_57_29_371Z-debug.log
```

I hope you guys can help me to point out where i should make changes so it can work successfully. thanks in advance !

Comment: Have you tried nuking the `node_modules` folder and installing again? `rmdir ./node_modules` and `npm install`. Also, what node version are you on? `node -v`

Answer (score 2):

after creating a project with create-react-app

```
create-react-app name
```

you have to go inside the created folder

```
cd name
```

and then run

```
npm start
```

again

Answer (score 0):

first create a folder in one Drive( D: or E:),open it in command prompt and create a react app like:

npm create-react-app project name

or

npx-create-react-app project name
cd project name
npm start